# Getting Error WAR packaging error: startup failed for grails war

Tags: grails, heroku

I am working on grails application and using **grails 2.3.3 version**. When I run grails app-run, it works fine, but for grails war, it throws `Error WAR packaging error: startup failed` with details following:

```
/home/vieenay/.grails/2.3.3/projects/VProcureFinal/gspcompile/gsp_VProcureFinal_layoutsspringSecurityUI_gsp.groovy: 2: unable to resolve class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils
 @ line 2, column 1.
   import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils
   ^

/home/vieenay/.grails/2.3.3/projects/VProcureFinal/gspcompile/gsp_VProcureFinal_layoutsspringSecurityUI_gsp.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class grails.plugins.springsecurity.SecurityConfigType
 @ line 3, column 1.
   import grails.plugins.springsecurity.SecurityConfigType
   ^
```

**Note:** I have added following plugins to buildconfig.groovy file to deploy on heroku.

```
compile(':heroku:1.0.1') {
        exclude 'database-session'
        }
        compile ':cloud-support:1.0.8'
```

Basically I am trying to deploy my grails app to Heroku. I can run my application locally successfully but even grails war does not work and throwing above error. I tried to search grails mailing list and stackoverflow but could not get solution.

Any idea why this is happening.Please let me know you need more code to be pasted.

Comment: hi @burt-beckwith, Is spring-security core 2.0 plugin workable with heroku:1.0.1?

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution?
I think I have a similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30888875/can-not-build-war-from-grails-project

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing "grails.plugins.springsecurity" anywhere when using the 2.0 plugin, something's wrong. From the error, it looks like you're still using the old version of the spring-security-ui plugin - make sure you're using 1.0-RC1 of the UI plugin, and that any of the other spring-security-core secondary plugins (e.g. LDAP, ACL, etc.) are also the newer versions that are compatible with the 2.0 core plugin.

Comment: We're seeing the same error as @Vieenay, but can't move to 1.0-RC1 because this is used in production. Any idea why this would only affect the WAR (and not `run-app`)?