# Can not build war from grails project

Tags: grails, war, packaging

I'm building Grails (2.4.4) project and I faced very strange problem: I can 'run-app', I can 'compile' it but I can not 'war' or 'run-war' it.

There is a problem with Enum class (AlertType) from src/groovy directory when importing it to domain class (Alert):

```
| Compiling 258 GSP files for package [myProject].
| Error WAR packaging error: startup failed:
file:/home/me/workspaces/workspaceGrails/myProject/grails-app/domain/com/example/alert/Alert.groovy: 4: unable to resolve class com.example.alert.AlertType
@ line 4, column 1.
import com.example.alert.AlertType
```

Like I said: project is running in dev environemnt but I cannot build war and put it on production.

---

Here is a code of AlertType from src/groovy/com/example/alert:

```
package com.example.alert

public enum AlertType {
    NORMAL, INSPECTION, INSURANCE, FIELD_TASK, HERD_TASK
}
```

---

Here is a --verbose stacktrace from the newest GGTS:

```
Error | org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.ScriptExitException
Error | at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
Error | at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
Error | at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
Error | at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
Error | at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:391)
Error | at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error | at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
Error | at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error | at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:207)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:68)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
Error | at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
Error | at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error | at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
Error | at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error | at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:166)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
Error | at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
Error | at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error | at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
Error | at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error | at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:207)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:68)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
Error | at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
Error | at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
Error | at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
Error | at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
Error | at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
Error | at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
Error | at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error | at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
Error | at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error | at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
Error | at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
Error | at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
Error | at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
Error | at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
Error | at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:809)
Error | at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
Error | at groovy.lang.GroovyObject$invokeMethod.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
Error | at groovy.lang.GroovyObject$invokeMethod.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
Error | at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:591)
Error | at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error | at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
Error | at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error | at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:166)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:61)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
Error | at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeWithGantInstance(GrailsScriptRunner.java:781)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeScriptFile(GrailsScriptRunner.java:573)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeScriptWithCaching(GrailsScriptRunner.java:472)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeScriptWithCaching(GrailsScriptRunner.java:423)
Error | at org.grails.ide.api.impl.GrailsConnectorImpl.executeCommand(GrailsConnectorImpl.java:160)
Error | at org.grails.ide.eclipse.longrunning.process.GrailsProcess.run(GrailsProcess.java:130)
Error | at org.grails.ide.eclipse.longrunning.process.GrailsProcess.main(GrailsProcess.java:93)
Error | at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error | at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
Error | at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error | at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:236)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:264)
Error |
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.ScriptExitException
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.api.BaseSettingsApi.exit(BaseSettingsApi.java:370)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.api.BaseSettingsApi$exit$1.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.packaging.GrailsProjectWarCreator.packageWar(GrailsProjectWarCreator.groovy:126)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.packaging.GrailsProjectWarCreator$packageWar$0.call(Unknown Source)
Error | at _GrailsWar$_run_closure2.doCall(_GrailsWar.groovy:43)
Error | at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error | at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
Error | at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error | at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
Error | at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
Error | at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
Error | at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
Error | at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
Error | at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
Error | at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:54)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
Error | at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
Error | at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor164.invoke(Unknown Source)
Error | at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error | at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:166)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
Error | at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
Error | at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor163.invoke(Unknown Source)
Error | at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error | at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:207)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:68)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
Error | at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
Error | at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
Error | at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor158.invoke(Unknown Source)
Error | at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error | at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
Error | at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
Error | at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
Error | at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
Error | at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
Error | at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1152)
Error | at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
Error | at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
Error | at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:807)
Error | at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
Error | at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1272)
Error | at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1166)
Error | at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
Error | at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
Error | at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
Error | at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor157.invoke(Unknown Source)
Error | at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error | at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:166)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
Error | at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
Error | at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor156.invoke(Unknown Source)
Error | at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error | at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
Error | at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
Error | at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
Error | at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
Error | at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
Error | at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
Error | at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:417)
Error | at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processClosure(GantMetaClass.java:81)
Error | at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processArgument(GantMetaClass.java:95)
Error | at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:128)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:81)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
Error | at War$_run_closure1.doCall(War.groovy:38)
Error | at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error | at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
Error | at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error | at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
Error | at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
Error | at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
Error | at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
Error | at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
Error | at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
Error | at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:54)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
Error | at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
Error | at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor164.invoke(Unknown Source)
Error | at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error | at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:166)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
Error | at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
Error | at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor163.invoke(Unknown Source)
Error | at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error | at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:207)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:68)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
Error | at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
Error | at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
Error | at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor158.invoke(Unknown Source)
Error | at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error | at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
Error | at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
Error | at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
Error | at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
Error | at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
Error | at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1152)
Error | at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
Error | at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
Error | at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:807)
Error | at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
Error | at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1272)
Error | at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1166)
Error | at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
Error | at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
Error | at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
Error | at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor157.invoke(Unknown Source)
Error | at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error | at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:166)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
Error | at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
Error | at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor156.invoke(Unknown Source)
Error | at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error | at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:207)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:68)
Error | at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
Error | at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
Error |
    ... 68 more`
```

Here is example repo for this error: https://github.com/majkelo/AgroErrorRepo
(problem occurs only when drools lib are added to BuildConfig)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ken Siprell, an author of Drools plugin for Grails, [fixed](https://github.com/kensiprell/grails-drools/commit/fcbf764d18de2bb7d8b89fa324916d117c13c95c#diff-d64b3b2f712ddb8296942a1099c56ff0) [this compile issue](https://github.com/kensiprell/grails-drools/issues/9#issuecomment-120603114).