# What's "grails package" actually do?

Tags: debugging, grails, ant, package, war

I'd like to debug packing my grails project into war file by '**grails war**' (because of an error described here: [Can not build war from grails project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30888875/can-not-build-war-from-grails-project)) so I'm looking for differences in (ant?) commands which are executed step by step by '**grails package**' (which my project does successfully) and '**grails war**' in it's packaging section (which ends up with error: *Error WAR packaging error: startup failed* ).

Comment: I suggest you start digging into the `_GrailsWar.groovy` and `_GrailsPackage.groovy` scripts that are included with your Grails install. There's where you will find what happens, step by step.

Comment: Yeah, I've already found them - I hadn't realized that gradle != ant...
but unfortunatelly I still didn't find an answer why my project can't package classes from /src/groovy :/